# How to create a WAN device on HG8245

Tags: port-forwarding

Am trying to forward my DVR ports on Huawei HG8245 . While configuring Dyndns rouetr is asking for WAN Device creation . How can create a WAN DEvice ?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Huawei Service Manual. Please find a link below:

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fenterprise.huawei.com%2Filink%2Fenenterprise%2Fdownload%2FHW_U_149045&ei=oz8-VNLZL5GM7AaipIHYAw&usg=AFQjCNEJaVtwGktKsd0suJtvO9X9GSUWZQ&sig2=4GY9wTXiGy6s4ALq9zktUg&bvm=bv.77412846,d.ZWU

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: link already now working...